# What do I do if I lost my restore DVDs and have a corrupted HD in my Macbook Pro 2010?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, restore

I have a Macbook Pro 2010 (Core2Duo), and I lost my original software and OS restore DVD. The one that came with the laptop. Now my HD volume is corrupted (many programs quit randomly now -- like iTunes, XCode, etc). What can I do? Can I just go buy an OS X Lion DVD, reformat my HD, and do a clean install? Or do I somehow have to get the original DVD that came with the Macbook Pro and start from there? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Lion **DVD** on sale, however, Apple sells Lion **USB Key**, that you can use to reinstall Lion on a new hard drive.

What you won't have, though, is iPhoto, iWeb, iDVD (I probably forgot some) that come when you buy a Mac.

But if you bought them on the Mac App Store, you'll be able to reinstall them at no charge.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Apple store nearby, they can provide you with replacements for your restore DVDs, usually for free. They may even be able to give you some suggestions on fixing your restore. It sounds like the drive is still working, so I would make a backup, do a fresh install and manually transfer the data you need, just to be on the safe side.

You can of course get the Lion USB installer, but if you can get replacement Snow Leopard DVDs for free, you'll save yourself $40 by installing Snow Leopard, then getting Leopard from the Mac App Store (Lion download is $29, Lion USB is $69).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to go to an Apple store where they can provide you with a replacement for your restore DVD.

If this is not an option, then you can use an OS X Lion install media on your Mac. It will work fine. You can either buy an [USB drive OS X Lion](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD256Z/A) directly from Apple, or you can burn yourself a DVD if you can manage to buy and download OS X Lion installer from App Store (this can be done from another Mac running either Snow Leopard or Lion).

If you want to burn your own DVD, here is the procedure to follow.

- Buy OS X Lion from the App Store and download it. Don't launch it yet.
- Locate the OS X Lion installed in the Finder, right click and select *Show Package Content*.
- Find the `SharedSupport` folder.
- Copy the file `InstallESD.dmg` to your desktop.
- Launch *Disk Utilies*, insert a blank DVD, select `InstallESD.dmg` and burn.